# Finding mathematical expression of expected value

Tags: integration, expected-value

I am trying to find the closed form expression of the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{b}e^{\frac{-1}{a^c}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{b})^c} \left ( \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{b}\right )^{c-1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx,$$
where
$b>0,a>0, 0<x<b,c>1$

Basically this integral is the expected value of pdf:
$$f(x)=c*\frac{1}{a^c}e^{\frac{-1}{a^c}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{b})^c} \left ( \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{b}\right )^{c-1} \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically this integral is the expected value of pdf:

$$f(x)=\underbrace{\frac{-c}{a^c}}_{<0}\times \underbrace{e^{\frac{-1}{a^c}\left(\frac{b-x}{xb}\right)^c}}_{>0}\times\underbrace{ \left(\frac{b-x}{xb}\right)^{c-1}}_{>0}\times\underbrace{\frac{1}{x^2}}_{>0}\cdot{1}_{(0;b)}(x)$$

As you can see, your pdf cannot be a density, being negative $\forall x$

I expect that after correcting your pdf, with a suited transformation it can be transformed in a Weibull distribution... but I wait your amendments before begin to think about it.

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in $\frac{-c}{a^c}$, it should be $\frac{c}{a^c}$. I've corrected the expression above. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint as well,  I will also start thinking about it.

Comment: @Math_manul : Transforming your rv in 

$$Y=\frac{b-X}{Xb}$$

Easy find that $Y\sim \text{Weibull}$ thus $E(Y)=a\Gamma(1+1/c)$ is immediate...I see some trouble in finding $E(X)$. May it be that reading your full problem a solution comes up

Comment: Thank you. Basically, pdf here is for the distribution of the reciprocal of a 3 parameter Weibull random variable with location parameter > 0.